# How to position image view on top of a photo correctly using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, merge, draw, photos

Currently I am able to save the photo with an image on top, however the top image is not located at the coordinate it is when appearing on the screen in a preview view.

```
fileprivate func mergeUIViews( ) -> UIImage?
{
    let bottomImage = photo
    let topImage    = uiViewInstance.image

    let bottomImageHeight = bottomImage.size.height
    let bottomImageWidth  = bottomImage.size.width

    let topImageHeight = uiViewInstance.frame.height
    let topImageWidth  = uiViewInstance.frame.width
    let topImageOrigin = uiViewInstance.frame.origin

    let bottomImageSize = CGSize(width: bottomImageWidth, height: bottomImageHeight)
    let topImageSize = CGSize(width: topImageWidth, height: topImageHeight)

    // Merge images

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bottomImageSize, false, 0.0)

    bottomImage.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: bottomImageSize))
    topImage   .draw(in: CGRect(origin: topImageOrigin, size: topImageSize)) // Where I believe the problem exists
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```

Comment: Did you print `uiViewInstance.frame.origin`? Is it a `CGPoint` you expected?

Comment: @Ryan In the storyboard I have the top image set horizontally and vertically in the center to test. However, once this code is run, and the merged image is saved to the photo library, the top image appears on the top left hand corner with a little spacing both horizontally and vertically

Comment: Stupid question, but have you checked what the newImage looks like? Is it possible that it also has the top image with an origin of (0,0)?

Comment: @dfd print(topImageOrigin) results in the point (63.0,230.0) However in the storyboard I set the constraints to be centered both horizontally and vertically ( which I would think would set its origin property internally? maybe? ). The topImage shows up at probably 1/5th the scale of the original image at the top left hand corner.

Comment: Okay, this sounds more like something related to layout - be it constraints or something else. Two thoughts - first, what does the newImage look like? If it's corrupt then you know the issue (I think you already see that). Second, can you provide more code? Particularly - but not limited to - constraints.

Comment: @dfd So after a couple hours of tinkering, Ive got the right output now, but it seems hacky. I will post an answer and if you can identify a better approach it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Glad you found something that works. Post your code/answer and I'll check.

Answer (score 0):

What works instead of using the actual captured photo's size, is setting the photo size to the view of the view controllers size. This resulted in the desired output of the entire screen showing the merged photos and the proper point for the origin of the overlaid image.

```
fileprivate func mergeUIViews( ) -> UIImage?
{
    let bottomImage = photo
    let topImage    = uiViewInstance.image

    let bottomImageSize = self.view.frame.size

    let topImageHeight = uiViewInstance.frame.height
    let topImageWidth  = uiViewInstance.frame.width
    let topImageOrigin = uiViewInstance.frame.origin
    let topImageSize   = uiViewInstance.frame.size

    // Merge images

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bottomImageSize, false, 0.0)

    bottomImage.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: bottomImageSize))
    topImage   .draw(in: CGRect(origin: topImageOrigin, size: topImageSize)) // Where I believe the problem exists
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```